# Using A Helper Function for POST Request

Tags: ios, swift, post, helper

I tried making a helper class for my POST request, and want to return the response. However, as post request is asynchronous, it made me feel a bit confused.

I tried returning NSString however it didn't let me return neither `response` nor `responseString`. It just let me put `return "A"`. I tried to use `-> NSURLResponse` but couldn't make it work either.

What is the proper way of making a helper method like this? (It's also fine if I make a check after I get response, and return true or false according to the response)

```
class func hello(name: String) -> NSString {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.thisismylink.com/postName.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "Hi, \(name)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
    return "A"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `dataTaskWithRequest` is asynchronous, the function will hit your return statement before the completion block is executed. What you should do is either setup a completion block for your own helper method, or passing some sort of a delegate object to the function so that you can call a method on it to let it know what the result of the webservice callback was.

Here is an example using a completion block:

```
class func hello(name: String, completion: (String? -> Void)){

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.thisismylink.com/postName.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "Hi, \(name)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        completion(responseString);
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

then to use it

```
<#YourClass#>.hello("name") { responseString in

    //do something with responseString
}
```

havent tested the code, but should be about right

Comment: note the line change `let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` changed NSString to String to be more swifty

Comment: also note i havent included any error handling code, you are on your own for how to handle that